# Skipping custom ViewGroup's child layout to improve perfomance

Tags: android, performance, user-interface, android-custom-view

I am creating custom `ViewGroup` with manual (touch) and animated resizing of it's child `Views`. Resizing is done by re-calculating child `View's` sizes and calling `requestLayout()`, like this (on `Animation`):

```
@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    for (int i = 0; i < childList.size; i++) {
        newSize[i] = startSize[i] + (int)(delta[i] * interpolatedTime);
    }
    requestLayout();
}
```

In `onMeasure()` and `onLayout()` I apply calculated sizes.
My questions are: can I skip `child.measure()` in `onMeasure()` and/or `child.layout()` in `onLayout()` if:

1. child's size is 0?
2. child's size and/or position in `ViewGroup` hasn't changed since last layout?